# I get this error during my mock test: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-test

I'm getting this error while trying run a controller test

This is the full error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookController':
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
 'bookService'; nested exception is
```

This is the test:

```
@Test
public void bookRemoveTest() throws Exception {
    securityService.autologin("admin", "admin");

    Book book = new Book();
    book.setId(1L);
    bookService.findOne(1L);

    expect(bookService.findOne(anyLong())).andReturn(book);
    replay(bookService);
    MvcResult result = mockMvc
            .perform(post("/book/remove")
                    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                    .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))


            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
            .andReturn();

}
```

And this is the controller I'm trying to test:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String remove(
                @ModelAttribute( "id" ) String id, Model model
        ) {
            bookService.removeOne(Long.parseLong(id.substring(8)));
            List<Book> bookList = bookService.findAll();
            model.addAttribute("bookList", bookList);

            return "redirect:/book/bookList";
        }
```

Personally I think the problem is coming from here:

```
     @Before
     public void setUp() {
            bookService = createMock(BookService.class);

            ReflectionTestUtils.setField(bookController, "bookService", bookService);

            userRepository= createMock(UserRepository.class);
            ReflectionTestUtils.setField(bookController, "userRepository", userRepository);

            mockMvc = standaloneSetup(bookController)
                    .setMessageConverters(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter())
                    .build();
        }
```

Here I am trying to perform mock injections so I can use my service in mock tests

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: yes I will update right now

Comment: @Shahzeb its there

Comment: Why do you write the mocking code yourself instead of using @InjectMocks?

Answer (score 2):

your test class should use @InjectMock and @Mock to mock both controller and service.

```
public class BookControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    BookController controller;

    @Mock
    BookService bookService;  // will be inject to BookController

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller)
                .setSingleView(mockView)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void bookRemoveTest() throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

For more detail : [PROPERLY TESTING SPRING MVC CONTROLLERS](http://blog.trifork.com/2012/12/11/properly-testing-spring-mvc-controllers/)